# Java Chef recipe not installing Java

Tags: chef-infra

I am pretty new to Chef. I wanted to install Java on my Chef Nodes through recipes. This is what I tried:

**default.rb** looks like this:

```
root@user:/chef-repo/cookbooks/java/recipes#cat default.rb 
        #
        # Cookbook Name:: java
        # Recipe:: default
        #
        # Copyright 2016, YOUR_COMPANY_NAME
        #
        # All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
        #

        include_recipe "java"
```

**metadata.rb** looks like this:

```
root@user:~/chef-repo/cookbooks/java# cat metadata.rb 
name             'java'
maintainer       'YOUR_COMPANY_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures java'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'

depends "java",     "~> 1.39.0"
```

And then I upload this cookbook by the following command:

```
root@user:~/chef-repo/cookbooks/java/recipes# knife cookbook upload java
WARN: Ignoring self-dependency in cookbook java, please remove it (in the future this will be fatal).
Uploading java           [0.1.0]
Uploaded 1 cookbook.
```

Then I log into my Chef-client node and execute this recipe:

```
root@client:/usr/share/java# sudo chef-client
Starting Chef Client, version 12.11.18
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["java"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - java (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 0 resources

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Client finished, 0/0 resources updated in 02 seconds
```

It looks like this has not installed anything.
I try and check java version and I get nothing.

```
root@client:~# java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

Can someone please let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: `include_recipe "java"` in default.rb file, did you check other recipe is name java, you should write java recipe

Comment: Yes, I checked, recipe name is 'java'. Link is here:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java

Comment: `knife cookbook list` can you list all cookbooks in chef-server, make sure you have uploaded java cookbook correctly.

Comment: You shouldn't name your cookbook the same as the community cookbook you are trying to work with.  Pick a prefix like `foo` and name your cookbook `foo_java` to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a cookbook called "java" that depends on another cookbook called "java". I suspect what you're trying to do is consume the community "java" cookbook:

- https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java

I highly recommend you install [Chefdk](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/) locally and start using tools like [test kitchen](http://kitchen.ci/) to test your cookbook locally and [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) to manage the upload of your cookbook and all its dependencies into your chef server.

The following is an example of installing Java:

- [Chef in local mode cookbooks only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717135/chef-in-local-mode-cookbooks-only/30721385#30721385)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark . Those links you shared really helped

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more specific than the other answers: you need to rename your wrapper cookbook something like `mycompany-java`.